# What happens when auto minor version for postgres is disabled and maintenance window is reached?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have few postgres RDS instances in which `auto-minor-version` is disabled. In recommended section of the RDS console, I can see maintenance window for `Old Minor Version`.

Wondering what would happen if that maintenance window is reached inspite of `auto-minor-version` disabled ?

I tried to manually adjusting the maintenance window to buy some time but I believe that should not be the case when I have disabled the Auto Minor version upgrade.

Comment: If your data are important to you, you should always use the latest minor version.

Comment: Yeah @LaurenzAlbe agree on this, but just wanted to push deadline for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

When the maintenance window is reached, RDS won't try to automatically upgrade the engine's minor version because it's disabled. So nothing will happen. The recommendation is just for your information, it doesn't do anything. You can either enable `auto-minor-version` or upgrade the engine version manually to make the recommendation disappear.

> If you want Amazon RDS to upgrade the DB engine version of a database
> automatically, you can enable auto minor version upgrades for the
> database.

... if you don't want automatic upgrades - don't enable it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Amazon applies some updates, at least on Aurora RDS, even when "auto minor version upgrade" is disabled. This happens during the maintenance window. The only way to avoid downtime (5-10 min) is to add more instances to the cluster (which effectively doubles costs, but it is what it is). These are likely critical security updates.